# How do I hide the mouse pointer after inactivity?

Tags: wayland, mouse-pointer, autohide, unclutter

I used to use unclutter for hiding the mouse pointer in X11 after some seconds of mouse inactivity.  Unfortunately, unclutter does not work under Wayland, to which I migrated.

How do I achieve the same effect with Wayland?  (Ubuntu default, not Sway.)  While I was successful that the mouse pointer is hidden after I start typing in *some* applications, this is not the same as time-of-inactivity-based hiding, and it does not work in all applications (cool-retro-term is a notable exception).

Comment: https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/hideaway can automatically move the cursor around (to a corner or edge of the screen for instance), but seemingly not hide.